# Как отменить ввод в первом InputBox, если во втором InputBox ничего не ввели? VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Есть два InputBox, в первом спрашивается имя, а во втором оценка. Как сделать так, что если вначале ввели имя, но затем не ввели оценку, то результат первого InputBox удаляется? (VBA)

Comment: Зачем что-то удалять-то? По нажатию кнопки ввода проверяете заполненность полей, и если что-то не так - выдаёте сообщение и не переходите к следующему шагу.

Answer (score 0):

После ввода имени записать его в переменную. Если оценка во втором `InputBox` не введена, завершить работу.

```
Sub testInput()
    Dim vName As Variant
    Dim lRating As Long
    
    vName = Application.InputBox("Впишите имя")
    If vName = "" Or vName = False Then Exit Sub

    lRating = Application.InputBox("Впишите оценку")
    
    If Val(lRating) > 0 Then
        Range("A2").Value = vName
        Range("B2").Value = lRating
    End If
End Sub
```